# Javascript not loading on Safari refresh (works in all other browsers though)

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I have this weird problem with the Safari (v.10.1.2) web browser.

If you go to my site: http://library.buffalo.edu, the carousel loads just fine. But if you refresh the browser, it collapses to the left. [screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDCOH.png)

I tried it on a couple computers with Safari and it does it on all of them. But on Chrome, Firefox and IE, it works just fine. I think it's a javascript problem, but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check the browser **developer** tools console for any errors - I assume Suffery has one of those

Comment: No errors in the web developer tools.